# Building toolchain with crosstool-ng on Mac OS X SL

Tags: macos, cross-compiling

I am trying to build toolchain for Linux on Mac.

I configure ct-ng as specified in docs/MacOS-X.txt(except that i use GNU soft from MacPorts and my partition is already case-sensitive). However when I try to build i get a lot of errors in shell files that looks like:

```
[ERROR]        called from '/Users/xxx/tmp/crosstool-ng-1.5.2/scripts/functions' at line # 250 in function 'CT_OnError'
[ERROR]        called from '/Users/xxx/tmp/crosstool-ng-1.5.2/scripts/functions' at line # 116 in function 'CT_DoExecLog'
[ERROR]        called from '/Users/xxx/tmp/crosstool-ng-1.5.2/scripts/functions' at line # 254 in function 'CT_DoForceRmdir'
[ERROR]        called from '/Users/xxx/tmp/crosstool-ng-1.5.2/scripts/crosstool-NG.sh' at line # 201 in function 'main'
[ERROR]  Look at '/opt/ct-ng/i386-unknown-linux-gnu/build.log' for more info on this error.
```

Considering that I get a lot of this same errors on different ct-ng shell scripts I think i missed something obvious. But I double checked configuration and cant determine cause of this problems.

Comment: Also it would be great if somebody who have successfully built toolchain for Linux i386 on Mac will post his config file for crosstool-ng.

Comment: Is this question really suitable for SO? I see that you've asked on their mailing list but you've not really provided a lot of information about your set up or the problem other than that its not working.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you ask on the crossgcc mailing list. You can subscribe at http://sources.redhat.com/ml/crossgcc/

The specific issue is currently unresolved. See these threads in the archive

- http://sourceware.org/ml/crossgcc/2009-12/msg00029.html
- http://sourceware.org/ml/crossgcc/2010-01/msg00023.html

Comment: In fact this I already did and the link you have provided are to my threads :)

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't notice. Good luck with making it work, then!